Vue3, how to make a same component to appear in the DOM when the component's state is updated?
Can you please show me the pattern vue3 how can I achieve next thing:
I have a button component to attache a file. And once the file is attached I need to show the next same component, the same as the previous - to be empty in order to attach the next file, and to keep this process infinite. I thought a recursive component pattern should be fitting here maybe (I just can't understand the algorithm), or resursive component is not the best choise?
I'm having some start sketch code.


//global store file
const file = ref(null)
const allAttachedFiles = ref([])
const allAttachedFile = // do I need also to modify this function cause I'll have more than a single file by pushing each file to the allAttachedFiles array ?

//
const attachFile = async (id sequence = 1) => {
    if (!file.value) {
      return
    }

    const filePath = ticketId + String(sequence)

    await uploadDocument({ file: file.value, filePath })
    await attacheFile({
      fileName: file.value.name,
      filePath,
    })
  }
//

// button component
<template>
  <AppRequestFromFieldFile v-model="formsStore.file" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { useRequestsFormsStore } from '@/stores/...'

   const formsStore = useRequestsFormsStore()
</script>   




use v-for for the buttons in the component, no recursion is needed

v-for will work only for n array length that has the exact number of items. But I need The component to be rerendered and added to the DOM after the previous file is attached and make it as an INFINITE loop

v-for array can have dynamic length. Initial length 1 and increases by 1 every time you attach a file.
